# Processes in Powershell

Tags: powershell, process

I have got a problem.
1.The first situation 
**Process has already started.**
And I want to do something after the current process is completed.
For example 
 
`$process=[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessesByName("notepad")` 
And 
`Register-ObjectEvent $process Exited -Action {}`
 
But in this case, it's not working 
How Can I Register Event "Exited"?
2. The Second situation
**The Process has not yet been started.**
How I can to wait for start process?)

Comment: `GetProcessesByName` returns an array of processes, `Register-ObjectEvent $process[0] Exited -Action {<# codez in here #>}`

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is what I was looking for a first question!

Comment: Hmmm.... And by the way IF ($process.HasExited) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part is answered by  Mathias R. Jessen with `[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessesByName("notepad") | foreach {Register-ObjectEvent $_ Exited -Action { ... } }`

For second part, the solution is below. Credit goes here [PDQ.com - Register-ObjectEvent](https://www.pdq.com/powershell/register-objectevent/)

You need to use WQL queries to monitor for process start event, then set up a query watcher that will fire an event in response of some process getting started, then listen with `Register-ObjectEvent` on that watcher. Code-copy-paste:

```
$Query = New-Object System.Management.WqlEventQuery "__InstanceCreationEvent", (New-Object TimeSpan 0,0,1), "TargetInstance isa 'Win32_Process'"
$ProcessWatcher = New-Object System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher $query
$Action = { New-Event "PowerShell.ProcessCreated" -Sender $Sender -EventArguments $EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance }
register-objectEvent -InputObject $ProcessWatcher -EventName "EventArrived" -Action $Action
```

Comment: Nice one, `Register-WMIEvent` is also an option here

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You can add that thing into this answer, it's c-wiki.

Comment: @Vesper
I don't like WMIEvent!) I'll try Vesper way! Thx a lot!

Comment: @Vesper I think that `New-Object Management.EventQuery` works better than `WqlEventQuery`

Comment: Another way for a first question
`Select * From __InstanceDeletionEvent 
Within 1 
Where TargetInstance Isa 'Win32_Process' 
And TargetInstance.Name = "$program.exe"`